# xubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 can't show my wallpaper at login screen

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background

In xubuntu 14.04, if I change the wallpaper, the background of login screen and lock screen change accordingly. In other words, backgrounds of login screen and lock screen are the same as my desktop wallpaper.

However, in xubuntu 16.04 and 15.10, when I want to login in, the background shows correctly 1 second, and screen flickers to the system's default wallpaper.

So, is this a bug in 16.04 and 15.10? How can I set all the backgrounds the same. In 14.04, the screen won't flicker at all after a boot or system suspend.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Most annoying is that the password field seems to lose focus for a bit so I type, but login fails because a letter is missing. Any luck fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a relatively similar problem.

FIRST: Make sure that in LightDM settings, you have checked "User Wallpaper if available"

Then, SECOND:
In my case, I think the problem was that I had encrypted my home folder (in which I had stored the custom wallpaper I wanted to be used as both the desktop wallpaper and the login-screen wallpaper.

Obivously, the problem with this setup was that the home folder (and hence the wallpaper to be used) was encrypted, and couldn't be accessed by the system.

The workaround (for me) was to open a file manager as root, and copy the wallpaper to the folder where the default system wallpapers are stored 
(for Xubuntu 16.04, it's /usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/).

I hope this helps solving your problem as well!

Answer (score 1):

## Files

For Xubuntu 16.04, configuration files are now in **/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/** and **/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/**. Files within those directories have a priority scheme where lower numbers execute first. I found the "background" field in two files located within the greeter directory: 01_ubuntu.conf; 30_xubuntu.conf.

## Wallpaper

Took a custom image file and put it into /usr/share/wallpapers/my_image.jpg. Changed the owner of the file to root with permissions of -rw-r--r--.

```
cd /usr/share/wallpapers
cp ~/my_image.jpg .
sudo chown root: my_image.jpg
sudo chmod 644 my_image.jpg
```

## Connect Wallpaper to Setup File

Changed 30_xubuntu.conf, line: "background=SOMEFILE" because it executes last. Now it is:

```
background=/usr/share/wallpapers/my_image.jpg
```

It would have been better to copy 30_xubuntu.conf to 31_my_xubuntu.conf and remove everything but the "background" line. That way software updates should not overwrite my changes.

## Resolution of Image

Looking in various directories I found many different resolutions of images. Find out what your resolution is:

```
   xrandr -q
```

Output:

```
   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
   LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
       1280x800      59.98*+
       1024x768      60.00  
       ...
```

**LVDS1** is the screen name, **1280** is the width, **800** is the height. I searched for images that were 1280x800 so that the aspect ratio would not change, but could have fixed any high res image with Gimp. If you use the correct ratio people won't look fat or tall.

Answer (score 0):

Not always needed to move wallpaper to /usr. Maybe simply checking the rights of wallpaper catalog and wallpaper file can help. E.g. you have `/home/username/image/wallpaper/mypic.jpg` Ensure that all dirs have `rwxr-xr-x` permission and the file have `rw-r--r--`. That was enough for me in addition to check LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings "Use user wallpaper if available" should be checked.